# How to complete Mission 6 in Battlefield Hardline?

Tags: battlefield-hardline

After I took down everyone in the scrap yard, I heard Boomer yell "Come On Man! It's hard to breathe in here!". I approached the gate and pressed the square button on my controller. This is supposed to put the card in the gate, but the gate wouldn't open. I tried using a breaching charge, but I died and had to start the mission all over again.
How do you get into the warehouse?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the crane controls and lower the car hanging from the electromagnet. Boomer is in the trunk and he has the key card